# Express.js how to allow multiple requests to be executed without blocking them

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, tedious

I have a website made with express js that receives numerous post requests.
These requests do not take that long to satisfy (despite interacting with a sql database) so no problem here.
However, when a request is made that runs a query that takes several minutes before it is satisfied the server hangs until the database provides a response.

The code I use for database queries has a structure like this:

**Server.js:**

```
//declaration of a lib developed by myself
var machineDataAnalysis = require('./MachineDataAnalysis.js')    

//handle post request
app.post('/loadAllEvents', function (req, res) {
  machineDataAnalysis.getAllEvents(function (resp) {
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(resp));
  })
  res.status(401);
})
```

**MachineDataAnalysis.js**

```
//declaration of a lib developed by myself
var SQLServer = require('./lib/SQLServer.js');
```

getAllEvents function (simplified):

```
var query = `SELECT *
        FROM [JobViewerCurrent].[dbo].[dbEvents]`;

SQLServer.newQuery(query, QuerySettings.configMachineDatabase(), function (result) {
      callback(result);
})
```

**SQLServer.js:**

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

module.exports = {
newQuery: function (query, config, callback) {
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    var resultValue = {
        columnTitle: [],
        line: []
    };
    //
    // Setup event handler when the connection is established. 
    connection.on('connect', function (err) {
        var result = [];

        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err)
        }
        // If no error, then good to go...
        request = new Request(query, function (err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
            }
        });

        request.on('row', function (columns) {
            result = [];
            columns.forEach(function (column) {//cycle every filed of a row
                if (column.value === null) {
                    result.push('NULL');
                } else {
                    result.push(column.value);
                }
            });
            resultValue.line.push(result);
        });

        request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
            //resultValue.result = result;
            connection.close()
            connection.cancel()
        });

        request.on('columnMetadata', function (columns) {

            var names = [];
            columns.forEach(function (column) {//cycle every filed of a row
                names.push(column.colName);
            });
            resultValue.columnTitle.push(names);
        });

        connection.execSql(request);
    });

    // Initialize the connection.
    connection.connect(connected);

    connection.on('end', end);


    function end() {
        callback(resultValue)
    }

    function connected(err) {
        if (err) {
             console.log('error');
        }

        process.stdin.resume();

        process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
            exec(chunk);
        });

        process.stdin.on('end', function () {
        });
    }
}


};
```

I remain available for clarification.

Thanks

Luke

Comment: express won't block, so I'm assuming it's something with your database layer causing this.   Looking at your code you appear to construct a new connection for every query, I don't use tedious but that seems strange.

Comment: Try to put your database request inside promises and put your responses inside on resolve method.

Comment: There are so many issues with your code that it's very difficult to pinpoint what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Two words: `Async/await`

Comment: Thank you guys.
Ok i try the first two. When I have news I will inform you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code with the changes you suggested but nothing changed.

(I also removed MachineDataAnalysis.js)

**Server.js**

```
var QuerySettings = require('./SqlConfig.js');
var databaseTest = require('./lib/SQL');
databaseTest.connect(QuerySettings.configMachineDatabase()).then(
  console.log("Connection established!")
)

app.post('/loadAllEvents', async (req, res) => {
  var query = `SELECT  *
  FROM [JobViewerCurrent].[dbo].[dbEvents]
    `;

  databaseTest.query(query).then(function (a) {
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(a))
  }, res.status(500))

})
```

**SQL.js**

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var connection;

function connect(config) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       connection = new Connection(config);

    connection.connect(function(err){
        if (err) {

        } else {
            resolve("done")
        }
    });
})
};

function disconnect() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    connection.close()
    connection.cancel()

    connection.on('end', function (err) {
        resolve("done")
    });
    //connection.on('error', reject("Error"))
  });
};


function query(query) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result = [];
    var resultValue = {
        columnTitle: [],
        line: []
    };
    // If no error, then good to go...
    const request = new Request(query, function (err, rowCount) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
        }
    });

    request.on('row', function (columns) {
        result = [];
        columns.forEach(function (column) {//cycle every filed of a row
            if (column.value === null) {
                result.push('NULL');
            } else {
                result.push(column.value);
            }
        });
        resultValue.line.push(result);
    });

    request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
        resolve(resultValue)
    });

    request.on('columnMetadata', function (columns) {

        var names = [];
        columns.forEach(function (column) {//cycle every filed of a row
            names.push(column.colName);
        });
        resultValue.columnTitle.push(names);
    });

    connection.execSql(request);

  });
}

exports.connect = connect;
exports.disconnect = disconnect;
exports.query = query;
```